# Как получить доступ к почте через Exchange используя Java

Tags: java

Не получается получить доступ, использую ews-java-api.
При выполнении кода ниже получаю microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.autodiscover.exception.AutodiscoverLocalException: The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.

Я так понимаю Exchange.asmx на нашем сервере нет (при задании адреса вручную находит только файл Services.wsdl), при этом возможность подключения существует - с телефона стандартными приложениями все подключается.

Подскажите пожалуйста куда копать...

```
public class MailUtil {
public static boolean sendEmail() {
    Boolean flag = false;
    try {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2); // your server version
        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("login", "password", "domain"); 
        service.setCredentials(credentials);
        service.autodiscoverUrl("mail@mail.com", new RedirectionUrlCallback()); 
        EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(service);
        msg.setSubject("This is a test!!!"); 
        msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("This is a test!!! pls ignore it!")); 
        msg.getToRecipients().add("mail@gmail.com"); 
        msg.send(); 
        flag = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return flag;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    sendEmail();
}

static class RedirectionUrlCallback implements IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl{
    public boolean autodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback(String redirectionUrl) {
        return redirectionUrl.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Если автодискавера нет, то вероятно надо указать протоколы, адреса руками. С ews-java-api не знаком, но логически должно быть.

Comment: Проблема в том, что нет стандартных адресов imap.domain.com, pop3.domain.com,  доступ к серверу только через domain.com порт 443, иначе решил бы с помощью JavaMail

Comment: Так вы нигде и не указываете, ни domain.com, ни 443. Пробовали варианты с `service.setUrl(new URI("<ews_url>"));` вместо `autodiscoverUrl`?

Comment: С этого я и начал, этот урл должен вести к Exchange.asmx которого у меня нет, либо его не там ищу.

Comment: А точно оно должно вести к .asmx? Судя по единственной фразе <ews_url>, я бы предположил, что речь идет от Exchange Web Services и оно ждет ссылку вида `https://mail.example.com:443/owa`

Comment: В JavaMail есть всё необходимое для работы по протоколам POP3/SMTP/IMAP. Зачем какие-то левые библиотеки и классы?

Comment: @Maxim, получил ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML.

Comment: @Igor Kudryashov, подскажите как в JavaMail установить коннект не имея imap.domain.com

Comment: Не понял ваш вопрос. Вы не знаете имя домена или ваш почтовый сервер не работает с протоколом IMAP?

Comment: @Igor Kudryashov, доступ к почте организован через RD Web Access. Для доступа с телефона есть сервер и домен, приложениям этого достаточно для работы. У меня есть домен с открытым портом 443, и есть страница типа https://imap.domain.com, на ней отображается картинка IIS7, но нет открытых портов (сервисы по поиску выдают нулевые результаты).  В итоге получаю java.net.UnknownHostException: imap.domain.com. Поэтому и пробую зайти с другой стороны...

Comment: С теми параметрами, что для телефона, подключаться пробовали? Инструкции [тут](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) Там же, в дистрибутиве, есть примеры. Раз телефон на Android работает, на JavaMail тоже должно работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/ нашел расположение файла и данные по серверу. Впрочем в моем случае это проблему не решило - получаю Bad Request при попытках манипуляций с почтой.
Возможно дело в том, что в ews нет 2013 версии Exchange...